# SQL joining 2 tables with some overlapping values

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to create one table out of the following 2 tables and running into a lot of problems.

Table 1 has the following:

```
Month,
Salesperson_Assigned,
Product1_Revenue
```

Table 2 has the following (different product):

```
Month,
Salesperson_Assigned,
Product2_Revenue
```

The problem is that while all the months are the same, there are some salespeople in Table 1 not in Table 2, and vice versa. Obviously the revenue is different. I want to join the tables to look like Month, Salesperson, Product1_revenue + Product2_revenue.

Here's the query I'm using:

```
SELECT
Table1.month,
Table1.salesperson_assigned,
sum(Table1.revenue + Table2.revenue)

FROM
Table1
INNER JOIN Table 2 ON (Table1.month = Table2.month) AND (Table1.salesperson_assigned = Table2.salesperson_assigned)
```

The output isn't correct even though I confirmed the revenue values in each individual table are correct. The output seems to be making up additional values for the salespeople who appear in only 1 table for the field that should be null.

Anyone had any advice for how to join the 2 tables properly so it acts similar to a pivot table, adding the unique values to the "salesperson assigned" column and adding the revenue for both columns, but when a salesperson is in only ONE table having it respect that there is a zero value for revenue?

Answer (score 1):

did you tried this way:

```
 SELECT
    Table1.month,
    Table1.salesperson_assigned,
    sum(Table1.revenue + Table2.revenue)

    FROM
    Table1 FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 on (Table1.month = Table2.month AND Table1.salesperson_assigned = Table2.salesperson_assigned)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally for these type of situations `FULL OUTER JOINS` are useful - but apparently MySQL does not support `FULL OUTER JOINS` see: [Full Outer Join in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql)

Update (without using right outer join):

```
create table table1
(month int
,salesperson_assigned int
,Product1_revenue int);

create table table2
(month int
,salesperson_assigned int
,Product2_revenue int);


insert into table1 values(1,10,100);
insert into table1 values(2,10,200);
insert into table1 values(1,11,40);
insert into table1 values(2,11,800);
insert into table1 values(3,11,400);


insert into table2 values(1,10,100);
insert into table2 values(2,10,200);
insert into table2 values(1,12,40);
insert into table2 values(2,12,200);

select 
table1.month
,table1.salesperson_assigned
,ifnull(table1.Product1_revenue,0) as Product1_revenue
,ifnull(table2.Product2_revenue,0) as Product2_revenue
,ifnull(table1.Product1_revenue,0)+ifnull(table2.Product2_revenue,0) as total_revenue
from table1
left outer join table2
on table1.salesperson_assigned=table2.salesperson_assigned and table1.month=table2.month
union 
select 
table2.month
,table2.salesperson_assigned
,ifnull(table1.Product1_revenue,0) as Product1_revenue
,ifnull(table2.Product2_revenue,0) as Product2_revenue
,ifnull(table1.Product1_revenue,0)+ifnull(table2.Product2_revenue,0) as total_revenue
from table2
left outer join table1
on table2.salesperson_assigned=table1.salesperson_assigned  and table1.month=table2.month
order by 2,1;
```

returns:

```
Month   salesperson_assigned    Product1_revenue    Product2_revenue    total_revenue
1       10                          100                 100                 200
2       10                          200                 200                 400
1       11                          40                  0                   40
2       11                          800                 0                   800
3       11                          400                 0                   400
1       12                          0                   40                  40
2       12                          0                   200                 200
```

ps:Please consider posting code to reproduce your data so that you can get quicker response.

Comment: The mysql variant run by my company does not allow right outer joins, only merge joins. Would replacing right outer join with merge join work?